# group by condition in a Full outer join

Tags: plsql

I have a  two table which has below information.

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

I want to join these two tables and get the ID, DATE,FINAL AMOUNT( Which is amount-deduct ) by group by of ID AND DATE.

I need the result as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.DATE, (t1.AMOUNT - t2.FINAL_AMOUNT) AS 'FINAL AMOUNT'
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX(DATE) AS 'MAXDATE'
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY ID
) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.DATE = t2.MAXDATE
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.DATE, t1.AMOUNT, t2.FINAL_AMOUNT
```